# Убрать пробелы в input , javascript

Tags: javascript, input

Реализован поиск по таблице следующим образом

```
   <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Введите данные" id="search-text" onkeyup="tableSearch()">

function tableSearch() {
    var phrase = document.getElementById('search-text');
    var table = document.getElementById('info-table');
    var regPhrase = new RegExp(phrase.value, 'i');
    var flag = false;
    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        flag = false;
        for (var j = table.rows[i].cells.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            flag = regPhrase.test(table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML);
            if (flag) break;
        }
        if (flag) {
            table.rows[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            table.rows[i].style.display = "none";
        }

    }
}
```

Подскажите как убрать пробелы при вводе в поле значений?

Comment: Получите значение из инпут и профильтруйте его, как-то так: ```let v = phrase.value.split('').filter(item => item !== ' ').join('');
 phrase.value = v``` Это будет работать и на вставку и на вписывание символов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот прошу, пользуйся

```js
const search = document.getElementById('search-text');

search.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  search.value = this.value.replace(' ', '');
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search-text">
```

Comment: При вводе значений работает, а если копипаст с пробелами?

Comment: @hello_v изменил ответ

Comment: попробуйте вставить "фывфыа       ыафы"

Comment: удаляется проблем, всё как хотел автор

Comment: по-моему он хотел пробелЫ. Хотя, кто знает.

Comment: Спасибо это подходит

Answer (score 0):

перед `var regPhrase = new RegExp(phrase.value, 'i');` добавить `phrase.value = phrase.value.replace(' ','')`